# How can I tunnel whole system through HTTP proxy?

Tags: 20.04, proxy, tunnel

I currently use Ubuntu 20.04. I need to use proxy to connect to internet. I have configure every program is use proxy because most software don't respect the `http_proxy` environment variable. I have tried to set proxy in Settings but most software don't care it. Is there any way to whole system through proxy? Is there any way to make a interface which will tunnel all request to HTTP proxy?

Answer (score 0):

First, configure proxy in Settings. Most GUI (at least GNOME) programs respect that configuration. Then install `proxychains` with this command:

```bsh
sudo apt install proxychains
```

After installing it, open it configuration located at `/etc/proxychains3.conf` (I'm not sure, refer `man procychains` for more information). It contains how to configure it in the comments, follow that. After you have successfully configured it, you can open any programs with it like this:

```bsh
proxychains command
```

Any network requests made will be redirected to the proxy. Also, you can open a shell with it so any network requests are redirected to the proxy like this:

```bsh
proxychains bash
```

Also, assume you want use `apt` with proxychains then don't use this command:

```bsh
proxychains sudo apt update
```

It won't work. Instead use this:

```bsh
sudo proxychains apt update
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to elaborate a bit please.
As I reads this you could setup a HAProxy acting opposite than usual in TCP mode, connecting to the actual proxy in your network. HAProxy honours and respects the proxy_protocol so it could do this seamlessly. Other possibility is to set up a local Squid Proxy catching everything and forwarding it to the other proxy.

Both of these solutions can work as invisible and you would not need to configure anything in any apps. However a setup like that is not default.

Comment: Please don't put comments in the answer section. That's now how StackExchange works.